# How to clean a project in Jdeveloper 10g

Tags: jdeveloper

How can I clean a project in Jdeveloper 10g. I want to upload a project to subversion, but before I'd like to clean it.

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Raúl.

Comment: What exactly do you want to clean? compiled files?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all classes folders from each project in the wordpress, delete all  '*.log' files  all '*.tmp' files. should add this suffixes in the .svnignore file.